# formatting the tooltip in noUISlider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, nouislider

I am using the noUISlider in my rails project.

```
noUiSlider.create( slider, {
start: [3],
connect: 'lower',
step: 1,
range: {
  'min': 1,
  'max': 9
},
pips: { 
  mode: 'steps',
  density: 20
},
tooltips: true,
format: {
from: function(value) {
    return (parseInt(value)+" days");
  },
to: function(value) {
        return (parseInt(value)+" days");
    }
}
});
```

I want it to be a measure of days in the tooltip. So I added the `format` part as above. But `start: 3` wont work anymore. It starts from 1 instead. If I remove the `format`, `start` works fine.

I tried removing the `format` and editing the noUi-tooltip text property from js (appending "days"), but that doesnt work either.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3):

In `format`, the `from` function converts the value *from* the formatted string *to* a numerical value. You'll want to cast your input to a number there:

```
format: {
    from: Number,
    to: function(value) {
        return (parseInt(value)+" days");
    }
}
```