# Append character to tooltip in noUISlider

Tags: nouislider

I'm trying to get **noUISlider** to show the "tooltip" with `€` as part of it. Here is a working example of what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/d4nxcwwu/4/

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready( function() { 

  var topSlider = document.getElementById('price_slider');
  noUiSlider.create(topSlider, {
      tooltips: [wNumb({ decimals: 0 }), wNumb({ decimals: 0 })],
      behaviour: 'drag-tap',
      connect: true,
      range: {
          'min': 10,
          'max': 500
      },
      // snap: true,
      start: [10, 500]
  });

    topSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function ( values, handle, unencoded, isTap, positions ) {
        $('#price_from').val(parseInt(positions[0]));
        $('#price_to').val(parseInt(positions[1]));
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="padding:100px">
    <div id="price_slider"></div>
</div>

From: <input type="text" id="price_from" /><br>
To:<input type="text" id="price_to" />
```

The page works, but what I want / need is for the tooltip to show the value like:

> €1234

not just

> 1234

The values in the input are fine (I don't want them appended to anything)

I've played around with the `format` function, but it doesn't seem to do what I want / am expecting.

```
format: {
    from: function(value) {
           return parseInt(value);
    },
    to: function(value) {
            return parseInt(value);
    }
},
```

FWIW, I came across this post, but couldn't get it working: [formatting the tooltip in noUISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361098/formatting-the-tooltip-in-nouislider)

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to add the `€` sign in the `to` function in the `format` option, as in the question you reference.

Comment: @Lg102 - thanks for the reply. I just came back to this, and ended us just using `wNumb` to process it (as that was the example given on their site): `tooltips: [wNumb({ prefix: "&euro;", decimals: 0 }), wNumb({ prefix: "&euro;", decimals: 0 })],` - basically just add the "prefix" option, as per wNumb's documentation. I was trying not to that extra module, but looking at the docs it actually seems like it could be a helpful module for us :)